# Is eUTxO a generalisation of UTxO

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, smart-contract, utxo

To me it sounds like UTxO is a very specific implementation of the more general eUTxO protocol. So could eUTxO be (in theory) be used to implement UTxO? Not that one would - but just to understand the distinction between the two.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of regular Bitcoin-like UTXO's as a subset of all possible eUTXOs possible to construct on Cardano. Transactions that simply transfer ADA from one wallet to another (and nothing else) are examples of bitcoin-like UTXO's. eUTXO extends this core functionality by allowing one to attach arbitrary data and logic to each transaction, enabling complex lock-and-key mechanics that go way beyond simple public-private key transfers.

So to answer your question - yes; classic UTXO's are already implemented in Cardano and have been since genesis. UTXO's are to eUTXO's like squares are to rectangles.

Read more about the [eUTXO model](https://docs.cardano.org/plutus/eutxo-explainer) in the official Cardano Documentation